# scalar arithmetic in Stata

Tags: stata, math

Riddle me this:

```
scalar bah = .1*1000.01
display bah

   1

scalar list

   bah =    100.001
```

`display` seems to deliberately show the wrong number. Why? What is the standard way of checking the value of a scalar? `scalar list` seems like it would be a mess if using many scalars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is off-topic for this site. Stack Overflow seems better. Moderators should probably move it.

Try something like:

```
display %18.0g bah
```

(See `help format`)

or

```
display scalar(bah)
```

See also `help scalar` and the respective manual entry **[P] scalar**

Comment: Thanks, Roberto. And apologies to moderators for putting the question here; I should've known it was better on SO.

Comment: Just to note that by default `display bah` gives me `100.001`. Not sure why this is not the case for you. I'm using Stata 13.

Comment: Hm, now that I think about it again, I still don't get why `display` would show `1`. No possible formatting could transform `100.001` into `1`... That strikes me as broken.

Comment: That seems correct. I don't understand what you mean by broken. If you have a variable that starts with `bah`, you are displaying its first value.

Comment: Ah -- I made a rookie mistake. I'd delete the question as too localized (or the modern equivalent) if you hadn't answered already. Superfluous narrative: I had a variable named `bah` and apparently `display varname` simply prints the first element (which seems like a silly thing to do to me). I had also earlier performed an arithmetic operation that gave a result starting with `.` and didn't see/notice the dot, thinking it was just part of the results window's margin, and so was very suspicious of `scalar` and `display`.

Comment: The Stata point of view on `display` is that it is a silly thing to request the display of an entire variable, which could be billions of values, on a single line, which is the default space in which `display` shows stuff. The original design decision was to allow that syntax as legal, but just give a token display of the first value. It's not that the request is nonsensical; it's just impractical. The deeper point here is that scalars and variables share the same name space.